# Caching WCF service and Convert data as Async

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, caching

We are trying to cache the data of a WCF service, So when the data is available in cache memory we need to return cached data from the cache as AsyncResult because the data is an object type and the Start method is IAsyncResult.

Here I can't change the return type because its an abstract member in the helper class.

As well as I cant check from the parent page caching available and pass because this needs to be changed globally so those who are consuming this service can make use of it.

```
public override IAsyncResult Start(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
  {
   if(cache.Get("key")
     {
      //Needs to return the result Async format which is there as object in cache.
     }
  svc = new service.GetData(m_url);
  if (m_debug_mode) // not thread safe
    {
      return ((service.GetData)svc).BeginCallDataDebug(request, cb, extraData);
    }
   return ((service.GetData)svc).BeginCallData(request, cb, extraData);
   }

public override void End(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
    try
      {
        data = ((service.GetData)m_svc).EndCallData(ar);
        if(data !=null)
        cache.Add("key", data, null, absoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
      }

   catch(Exception ex)
    {
     Log(ex.message);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) implements `IAsyncResult`.

If the data is found in the cache, you can return a completed `Task` with the result via [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8). Otherwise, you make the call to the service.

```
public override IAsyncResult Start(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
{
    Object cachedData = cache.Get("key");
    if (cachedData != null)
    {
        // Return cached data.
        return Task.FromResult<object>(cachedData);
    }

    // Make call to the service.
    svc = new service.GetData(m_url);
    if (m_debug_mode) // not thread safe
    {
        return ((service.GetData)svc).BeginCallDataDebug(request, cb, extraData);
    }
    return ((service.GetData)svc).BeginCallData(request, cb, extraData);
}
```

In the `End` method, you can check the `IAsyncResult` type to access the result value.
*(Or you set a state flag/field in the `Start` method about whether your called the service or not; you could check the service `svc` field which will be null when cached data is being used.)*

```
public override void End(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Task<object> task = ar as Task<object>;
        if (task != null)
        {
            data = task.Result;
        }
        else
        {   
            data = ((service.GetData)m_svc).EndCallData(ar);
            if(data !=null)
                cache.Add("key", data, null, absoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope I can give you bounty after three hours of the answer acceptance, You really solved my problem buddy. Thanks a lot for that. I missed the core concept of Task and Async itself.

Comment: But I am facing one problem that while initializing the service it will be set for 10s time out since we take data from cache if svc is not initialized in such case it throwing null in case of while setting the timeout log.

Comment: by returning the result from Task result task is going to active in the back end and its like deadlock and service is getting timed out. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: Can you post a new question with that? We'll need some details about how the service is being used is such a scenario. At the moment, I don't see how the service is involved in case data gets found in the cache.